# Изучаю возможности оптимизации запросов. Подскажите, что делать со влоежнным подзапросом

Tags: sql

Суть: есть таблица с клиентами, а есть таблица с их счетами. считаю сумму всех счетов у клиентов физ.лиц

```
Select 
  Cus.Cust_Id, 
  Cus.Fed_Id, 
  i.first_name + ' ' + last_name as Name, 
  Acc2.Sum_Avail_Balance 
From 
  Customer Cus, 
  (
    Select 
      Acc.Cust_Id, 
      Sum(Acc.Avail_Balance) As Sum_Avail_Balance 
    From 
      Account Acc 
    Group By 
      Acc.Cust_Id
  ) Acc2, 
  individual i 
Where 
  Cus.Cust_Id = Acc2.Cust_Id 
  and cust_type_cd = 'I' 
  and Cus.Cust_Id = i.Cust_Id;
```

Comment: так обычный join же!

Comment: дали задание оптимизировать этот запрос

Comment: вот и оптимизируй join-ом таблицы `Account`

Comment: а сумму всех счетов считать в основном селекте?

Comment: да! и не забудь про `Group By`.

Comment: Действительно, чего это я сразу так поступила... Большое спасибо!